# servlet can't get option value from jsp

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, html-select

I'm doing a java web application using jsp and servlets.
I have a form and I retrieve different values from my db to populate an option. This is my form:

```
    <form class="form" action ="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/aggiungiLibro" method ="post">
    <div class="form__group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Titolo" class="form__input" name = "titolo"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form__group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Quantità disponibile" class="form__input" name="quantita" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form__group">
    <select class="form__input" name="autore">
        <c:forEach items="${listaAutori}" var = "autore" >
            <option value="${autore.idAutore}"><c:out value="${autore.nome} ${autore.cognome}" /></option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
        <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Inserisci nuovo libro</button>
    </form>
```

In the servlet I retrive my data with

```
String titolo = request.getParameter("titolo");
int quantita = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantita"));
int autore = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("autore"));
```

I get right values for 'titolo' and 'quantita' but I get the string '${autore.nome}' for 'autore'.
It seems like it doesn't replace the string with the actual value.
The field idAutore is spelt right.
(In the jsp page I see the correct values for ${autore.nome} ${autore.cognome})

Anyone can help me please? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the actual HTML generated by your JSP for the select tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved replacing this:

```
<option value="${autore.idAutore}">
```

with this:

```
<option value="<c:out value='${autore.idAutore}' />">
```